# Mathematicians endorsing platonism -- examples?

Tags: big-list, foundations, philosophy

Take platonism to be the view that there are abstract mathematical objects which exist independently of us as mathematicians and our language, thought, and practices.

Looking at the *Stanford Encylopedia of Philosophy*'s article on [Platonism in the Philosophy of Mathematics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/platonism-mathematics/), which offers more or less that definition, it is notable that we don't get any straight quotations from mainstream *mathematicians* expressing some commitment to platonism.

Yet it is often said that many mathematicians incline to platonism (when they have any 'philosophical' view at all). The great G.H. Hardy is quoted as an exemplar:

> I believe that mathematical reality lies outside us, that our function is to discover or *observe* it, and that the theorems which we prove, and which we describe grandiloquently as our ‘creations’, are simply our notes of our observations.

Now, I'm not interested here in discussion of whether platonism is *right* (inappropriate here!). Rather, my question is: what telling quotations from more recent well-known mathematicians could you offer students, giving *other* examples of explicit endorsement by working mathematicians (as opposed to philosophers) of some kind of platonism?

Comment: Gödel? Woodin? Definitely not me, though.

Comment: My strong suspicion is that among those mathematicians who profess on paper to be platonists with respect to mathematical objects, the vast majority satisfy this property: that if you were to sit them down in your office, as you would an undergraduate for a tutorial, and if you asked them a series of incisive questions challenging their platonist claims, they would soon realise that they haven't actually thought through the relevant philosophical issues, and they would then drop their commitment to platonism like a hot potato.

Comment: @ChrisSanders I suspect that you are indeed right!

Comment: I don't know if Penrose counts as a mathematician, but he has a "three-world" theory concerning reality https://astudentforever.wordpress.com/2015/03/13/roger-penroses-three-worlds-and-three-deep-mysteries-theory/

Comment: See also this quotation from Hermite: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platonisme_math%C3%A9matique#Positions_paradigmatiques_de_math%C3%A9maticiens_modernes

Comment: Gödel, definitely.

Comment: @ChrisSanders I remember reading a humorous philosophical dialogue between a student and a mathematics professor in which the latter is cornered into explaining that mathematicians really only speak *as though* they were platonists, since of course none would be willing to deny the basic tenets of empiricism endorsed by all reasonable people.

Comment: Here are two more links that claim that almost all mathematicians are platonists:  http://www.borovik.net/selecta/uncategorized/why-are-so-many-mathematicians-platonists/?msclkid=2f330fb9a94611ecaf2e7d659be35ce8 https://www.reddit.com/r/askphilosophy/comments/azw2se/are_most_mathematicians_platonists_or_nominalists/?msclkid=2f3376f9a94611ecbc0cab358d814b92 This link shows philosophers of math are 60/20 Platonist vs nominalist https://philpapers.org/surveys/results.pl?affil=Target+faculty&areas0=47&areas_max=1&grain=coarse

Answer (score 1):

"Platonism" is an awfully unfortunate naming that is unfair both to Plato's philosophy and to the intended view of the mathematical world and distorts the perceptions of both of them.

I don't think a mathematician's self-image does not differ radically from a physicist's, albeit working out her way in a different universe: *Inventing* methods and techniques, *finding out* relations, sometimes *introducing* objects, sometimes *discovering* them.

Hence, I suspect that it is quite a hopeless endeavour to come across interesting examples of explicit endorsement of "Platonism" (as used by many philosophers of mathematics).

Notice that G. H. Hardy somehow felt the need to justify his art -overwhelming majority of the mathematicians didn't and don't. Why did he? I don't know; but I observe that he was a man of an era when science and technology had begun to employ enormously sophisticated mathematics.